# i got out of memory when i am reading large amount of data with datareader in web api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, datareader

There is large data in sql server database and i have made an api to read record. i used data reader to read all the data, when i test the data with google chrome, it said out of memory in te chrome and i want to use data set to control these data. how can i add data set into data reader or i need change to data table to use data set in my code? or are there any other solution to control large amount data.

my code:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            List<TestClass> draft = new List<TestClass>();
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser";
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                draft.Add(new TestClass()
                {
                    UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
                    Name = sdr.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : sdr.GetString(1),
                    Mobile = sdr.IsDBNull(2) ? string.Empty : sdr.GetString(2),
                    Age = (sdr.GetValue(3) !=DBNull.Value)? Convert.ToInt32(sdr.GetValue(3)) : 0,
                    Date = (sdr.GetValue(4) !=DBNull.Value)? Convert.ToDateTime(sdr.GetValue(4)): (DateTime?)null
                });
            }
            return Ok(draft);
        }
```

my class:

```
public class TestClass
    {
        
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        
        public int Age { get; set; }
        
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The OOM could be with the List class and not due to the DataReader. In any case, you should only read data that is required for processing in the current scenario and not all rows. Use a WHERE clause in your SQL query to limit rows to only those that are needed.

Comment: Side note: `using SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);` - note `using` - do not forget to `Dispose` `IDisposable`

Comment: @Shameel this query is for sync data to other server so this get function is needed

Answer (score 0):

When any process gets triggered, a separate virtual space is assigned to that process. Any program deals with `virtual` space not with `physical memory`, `Garbage Collector` deals with the same virtual memory to allocate and de-allocate memory.

`out of memory` happens due to virtual space is full

I would try in this way:

```
int limit = 50 // limit for data to get from DB.

public IHttpActionResult Get(int offset)
{
    List<TestClass> draft = new List<TestClass>();
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn))
    {
        string sqlquery = $"SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date From tbluser order by UserID offset {offset} rows fetch next {limit} rows only";
        sqlconn.Open();
        using(SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn))
        {
            using(SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    draft.Add(new TestClass()
                    {
                        UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
                        Name = sdr.IsDBNull(1) ? string.Empty : sdr.GetString(1),
                        Mobile = sdr.IsDBNull(2) ? string.Empty : sdr.GetString(2),
                        Age = (sdr.GetValue(3) != DBNull.Value)? Convert.ToInt32(sdr.GetValue(3)) : 0,
                        Date = (sdr.GetValue(4) != DBNull.Value)? Convert.ToDateTime(sdr.GetValue(4)): (DateTime?)null
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    return Ok(draft);
}
```

Comment: my api cannot change the sql query, so other method would be great.